# Laravel Mysql Table Joins

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables in a database, one called ticket and one called status(status of a certain ticket like new or completed)...Every time a user adds a ticket i want that status table to be updated with the ticket id and a status message.

Is the only way to do this with MYSQL table joins?

```
public function userSubmitTicket() {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), ['subject' => 'required', 'message' => 'required']);

        //if one or more of the text boxes dont contain data, the validator fails and user is returned backa to redo the form
        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages());
        }

        $user = Auth::user();
        $userId = $user->id;

        $subject = Input::get('subject');
        $message = Input::get('message');
        $date = new DateTime();

        $ticket = Ticket::insert(array('id' => null, 'date_in' => $date,
            'originator_id' => $userId, 'assigned_to_id' => 0, 'date_out' => null,
            'priority' => 3, 'subject' => $subject));

        $ticketID = Ticket::select('id')->limit(1)->get();

        foreach($ticketID as $id){

            $status = Status::insert(array('id' => $id, 'description' => 'New'));
        }
```

This was one way I tried, but i know it doesn't work now.

Comment: Besides the fact that this code could be optimized using relations, I think the mistake is `'id'` instead of `ticket_id` in the `Status::insert` statement

Comment: I dont see how thats the problem since $id is really the $ticketId i got from the ticket table?

Comment: Not `$id` but `'id'`. The column name, the key of your array.

Comment: So naming it to ticket_id, it will know to use the id from the ticket table?..'id' and 'ticket_id' sure are named different, but they represent the same thing: an id for the status table which represents a ticket id...im not sure how renaming a column name will help solve the problem for trying to add an id to the status based on which ticket id it is?

Comment: Well I don't know your db model, but I assumed the status table references the ticket with a foreign key and after Laravel naming convention, this column in the status table would be called `ticket_id`.  If my assumption is wrong, please update your question with the necessary information about your database schema

Comment: Well the original question is wether or not table joins are the way to go here, not so much changing the database.  Would table joins work?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but joins are used to *retrieve* data and not to insert new rows (and that's what you want to do isn't it?)

Comment: Yea, maybe I haven't explained myself well.  Yea I want to insert into the status table('id') the ticket id from the ticket table('id') and thought i would use table joins to retrive the id from the ticket table and insert it into the status table.  I guess theres a better way your saying?

Comment: Take a look at The Alpha's answer. That's pretty much what I would do

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
class Ticket extends Eloquent {

    //...
    protected $guarded = array(); // Check mass-assignment

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Status', 'ticket_id');
    }
}

class Status extends Eloquent {

    //...
    protected $guarded = array(); // Check mass-assignment
}
```

In this case `status` table must contain the `ticket_id` field as foreign key to build the relationship. So, if everything is alright then you may use something like this:

```
// Create a new Ticket
$ticket = Ticket::create(array(...));

// Create a new Status
$status = Status::create(array('description' => 'New'));

// Save the relationship
$ticket->status()->save($status);
```

In this case, I've assumed that, both of your tables/models have the `primary key` set to `id` field.